# Flutter: Issue when opening 10.000 files: StackOverflow

Tags: dart, file, visual-studio-code, stack-overflow

I just generated 10000 files in the Flutter app project in VSC:
{placeholder0, placeholder1 ..., placeholder10000}

Each file contains simple widget returning next Placeholder, like `Placeholder0` widget  returns `Placeholder1` widget and so on.. where Placeholder10000 returns just Text('test').

(What I also noticed VSC behaviour is getting strange once so much files is placed inside the project, like `Dart Analyzer` is  super lagging. I could not fint any info about number of files limitations within the project). Actually is it possible to run the project with such of big number of files inside it?

Once I put `Placeholder0` widget in the body of my `HomePage` try to run the app on simulator (iOS Simulator) i got following StackOverFlow error:

```
The relevant error-causing widget was
Placeholder453
lib/placeholders/placeholder452.dart:9
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _HashBase._isDeleted (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:198:3)
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin._init (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:429:24)
#2      _LinkedHashMapMixin._rehash (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:399:7)
#3      _LinkedHashMapMixin._insert (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:456:7)
#4      _LinkedHashMapMixin._set (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:511:7)
#5      _LinkedHashMapMixin.[]= (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:499:5)
#6      MapMixin.addAll.<anonymous closure> (dart:collection/maps.dart:129:11)
#7      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:617:13)
#8      MapMixin.addAll (dart:collection/maps.dart:128:11)
#9      _InternalLinkedHashMap.addAll (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:301:11)
#10     DiagnosticsNode.toJsonMap.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1646
#11     DiagnosticsNode.toJsonMap
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1661
#12     DiagnosticsProperty.toJsonMap
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:2666
#13     DiagnosticsNode.toJsonList.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1686
#14     MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:413:31)
#15     ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:342:26)
#16     new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:189:27)
#17     new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
#18     new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:51:28)
#19     ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:213:44)
#20     DiagnosticsNode.toJsonList
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1687
#21     DiagnosticsNode.toJsonMap.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1648
#22     DiagnosticsNode.toJsonMap
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1661
#23     DiagnosticsNode.toJsonList.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1686
#24     MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:413:31)
#25     ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:342:26)
#26     new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:189:27)
#27     new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
#28     new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:51:28)
#29     ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:213:44)
#30     DiagnosticsNode.toJsonList
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1687
#31     DiagnosticsNode.toJsonMap.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1648
#32     DiagnosticsNode.toJsonMap
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1661
#33     WidgetInspectorService._nodeToJson
package:flutter/…/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:1606
#34     WidgetInspectorService._reportStructuredError
package:flutter/…/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:937
#35     FlutterError.reportError
package:flutter/…/foundation/assertions.dart:1184
#36     _debugReportException
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6493
#37     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4908
#38     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4604
#39     ComponentElement._firstBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4859
#40     ComponentElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4853
#41     Element.inflateWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3863
#42     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3592
2
...
#4116   Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4604
#4117   ComponentElement._firstBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4859
#4118   StatefulElement._firstBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5041
#4119   ComponentElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4853
...     Normal element mounting (27 frames)
```

Comment: what happens if you only have 10 placeholders

Comment: It works normally, returning/showing 'test' on the screen.

Comment: Same problem occurs for 1000 files, listing exceptions below:

Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4606 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4606
The relevant error-causing widget was
Placeholder691
lib/placeholders/placeholder690.dart:9
═════════════════════════════════════

Comment: Would you please show code of how your placeholders are added to the widget tree? Also, for performance, you could try splitting up the placeholder files into multiple subdirectories, i.e. max 100 placeholder files per directory.